# How can I copy and paste in and out of a Gnome Boxes VM?

Tags: virtualization, fedora

This is specifically for Gnome Boxes virtualization manager and a redhat VM.

[On this page](https://mike42.me/blog/tag/gnome-boxes), it mentions a feature called "Share Clipboard" but Boxes doesn't have any settings that I can see in the menu bar. I know how to install spice-vdagent if only I could find out how to invoke it.

[Gnome Boxes page](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-boxes/stable/clipboard.html.en) says its in General tab but its not:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGPZ8.png)

Gnome Boxes uses libvirt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to specify what hypervisor your using. If your using VMWare you need to install VMWare tools to have this functionality.

Comment: @mully I'm using Gnome Boxes... so it must be using libvirt

Comment: @Community Its pretty clear Mr.Bot. How do I enable copy paste in Gnome Boxes since I can't find "Shared Clipboard" feature that is mentioned at the URL provided..

Comment: @pleskymajor My bad... Does this help any: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-boxes/stable/clipboard.html.en

Comment: @mully My bad for the pathetic search. It is right here in Gnome help yes I see that. The feature is missing in my Boxes but I probably did something wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by simply installing `spice-vdagent` on both host and guest OS and restarting my Guest OS.

> My Guest OS: kali linux "sudo apt install spice-vdagent"
>
> My Host OS: Fedora "sudo dnf install spice-vdagent"

Comment: That worked for me, but I had to restart the VM. Thanks.